# bzr push bzr+ssh gives me an error on webfaction

Tags: push, bazaar, webfaction

I setup bzr repo on both server and local. I am trying to push the code from my local directory to server, I am using the following command:

```
bzr push bzr+ssh://<username>@<username>.webfactional.com/myrepo
```

it asks for password and then gives me the error that bzr comman not found.
does anybody know what do i miss here? I think something is wrong from the server side, do you know how i should setup the servers side correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the

export PATH=/home/< webname>/bin:$PATH

to .bashrc solved the issue :)